# Excel: change formulas based on value in drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to be able to quickly check my paycheck in Excel. I wrote some numbers from my paycheck to rows based on the according month.

Because it is easier to read, I made the calculation not horizontal but vertical, as seen in the picture bellow. The problem is, that it is not easy to quickly link data from the table to the calculation itself.

[image: My table]

My idea is, that the calculation would change based on the month I would like to calculate, which would be selected in some form of drop down list. Is it possible to tell Excel - when I select the month in this drop down list, change the formula in this column based on the row, where that month is?

Comment: its hard to answer from the info you have provided, but yes you can do this in a number of ways, ismplest would be VLOOKUP, or HLOOKUP, or INDEX and MATCH

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Metchik

Its not actually the formula that changes, but the references in those formulas. The basic math (add or substract) says the same. So if you select the n'th month you want to offset the references F2 to I2 by (n-1) rows.

To add to what PeterH said, the most common way to do this is with VLOOKUP. VLOOKUP will search the first column in your data table for a match, then return a value in that row from an adjacent column you specify. E.g.

```
=VLOOKUP("February",A2:I4,COLUMN(G2),FALSE)
```

will return the value in G3.

An alternative that makes a bit more sense and is actually less computationally demanding on your PC, would use MATCH and INDEX. Match returns the row index for a matching value. E.g.

```
=MATCH("February",A2:A4)
```

will return 2 (the second cell in the vector A2:A4). You should place this match formula in E9 (make the text white to hide it) and use this index or offset in the formulas in H14 to H18. Now index simply returns the n'th value in a vector, e.g.

```
=INDEX(G2:G4,E9) will turn the value in G3 and,    
=INDEX(H2:H4,E9) will turn the value in H3
```